# java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: application/json; charset=UTF-8

Tags: java, android, json

I have a problem in this Android code snippet:

```
public Object post(String path, Object payload, Class<?> responseType) throws Exception {
    URI uri = buildUri(path);
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
    addHeaders(request);
    request.setEntity(new StringEntity(
            serialize(payload),
            ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    return op(request, responseType);
}
```

> 'StringEntity(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' in
>   'org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity' cannot be applied to
>   '(java.lang.String, org.apache.http.entity.ContentType)'

How can I correctly convert `ContentType` to `String`? I tried the use `toString()`, but got an error:

> java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: application/json; charset=UTF-8

I would be grateful for your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android version of [`StringEntity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html) does not have a constructor which accepts a `ContentType`. Use its [`setContentType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/entity/AbstractHttpEntity.html#setContentType%28org.apache.http.Header%29) method instead.